# Hello, can you help me out to make this art code more efficient?

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

can you help me out make this code more efficient. Today I started using p5.js and I would love to know how can I make this loops more efficient?

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
    background(0);
    noLoop();
}

function draw() {
    translate(width /2, height /2);
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(1);
    line(0, height, 0, -height)
    line(width, 0, -width, 0)
    for (var y = 250, x = 0; y >= 0; y-=50, x+=50) {
        line(0, y, x, 0)
    }
    for (var y1 = -250, x1 = 0; y1 <= 0; y1+=50, x1+=50) {
        line(0, y1, x1, 0)
    }
    for (var y2 = 250, x2 = 0; y2 >= 0; y2-=50, x2-=50) {
        line(0, y2, x2, 0)
    }
    for (var y3 = -250, x3 = 0; y3 <= 0; y3+=50, x3-=50) {
        line(0, y3, x3, 0)
    }
}
```

Here is the

[image: output of the code]

Comment: What is inefficient about your code?

Comment: If the shape is static, then create a p5.Renderer object ([`createGraphics()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/createGraphics)) or draw a line shape ([`beginShape(LINES)`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/beginShape))

Answer (score 0):

This should be a bit cleaner (and more efficient).

```
function setup() {
createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
background(0);
noLoop();
}
function draw() {
translate(width /2, height /2);
stroke(255);
strokeWeight(1);
line(0, height, 0, -height)
line(width, 0, -width, 0)
y = -250
x = 0
while (y != 0) {
  y += 50
  x -= 50
  line(0, y, x, 0)
  line(0, -y, -x, 0)
  line(0, -y, x, 0)
  line(0, y, -x, 0)
}
}
```